# Can I learn working with DAO in Spring without knowing Spring AOP?

Tags: spring, dao, spring-aop

I am learning Spring and am new to it, I want to skip learning the AOP and continue with learning how to work with DAO .Can I have a good understanding of DAO  without even knowing the AOP?

Comment: Yes. What made you think you couldn't?

Comment: The documentation of Spring 3.2.x has content arranged in such an order, I thought following the odd might hurt

Comment: What's "DAO programming"?

Comment: DAOs might use AOP, and Spring's transaction management uses it under the covers, but it's not strictly necessary to have a complete understanding of it before reading ahead.

Comment: @kryger edited for you ... thanks for pointing out ...

Comment: @DaveNewton you said "...it's not strictly necessary to have a complete understanding of it...." does that mean I should understand it a bit before diving in?

Comment: @RomanticElectron I think you should know it exists, but now that Spring has XML/annotations that hide all the AOP, it's not necessary to know *how* it works until there's actually an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. `Spring AOP` is not required for learning `DAO`. `AOP` is a different concept. But according to requirements, you can integrate both of them.